# Glossaries - Defining custom glossary style not working (anymore) / Throws error: "File ended while scanning use of \newglossarystyle"

Tags: longtable, glossaries, glossaries-extra

quite some time ago I tried to define my own glossarystyle using the `glossaries` and `glossaries-extra` packages.
At some point in early 2021 I managed to do so and was able to compile a working glossary. Then I abandoned the project for quite some time.
When I came back to work on in again a few days ago (Dec 2022), the code would not compile anymore.

This is what the last working output in Jan 2021 looked like:
[image: Last working glossary output]

The original definition of the newglossary style was this:
I had taken it from a 2010 guide on glossaries and idices.

```
\newglossarystyle{physchemunits}{% 
% Umgebung: longtable 
\renewenvironment{theglossary}% 
    {\begin{longtable}{@{}clp{7cm}c@{}}}% 
    {\end{longtable}}%  
% Tabellenkopf
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{% 
    \toprule%
    \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Unit} \\ %
    \midrule%
\endhead}% 
% keine Überschriften zwischen Gruppen 
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}% 
% Haupteinträge in einer Zeile: 
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[4]{% 
    \glssymbol{##1}% Symbol 
    & \glstarget{##1}{##2}% Name 
    & ##3% Description 
    & \si{\glsunit{##1}}% Einheit
    \\% Zeilenende
}% 
% Untereinträge wie Haupteinträge 
\renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{% 
\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}}%
% nichts zwischen Gruppen 
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}
```

After some research in the logs of the glossaries package I realized the newer versions of the package had shut down the use of some deprecated commands, which I then tried to replace to the recommended commands.

This was still not working, so I looked into other sources of errors.
At some point I suspected some part of the longtable environment to cause the error, so I tried to simplifly it - still not working.
I have been looking into the glossaries manual, several guides and of course the good old internet, but so far am at a loss to make the code work again. In the end, I tried to write it from scratch using the example 36 in the glossaries manual pp.335 and 336,but to no end.

So now I am stuck with a non-working minimal example:

```
%%% === ARARA === %%%
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: makeglossaries
%%% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }


\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

% ==============================
% ========== ACRONYMS AND GLOSSARY ==========

\usepackage[xindy, acronym, symbols, shortcuts, toc]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\glsaddstoragekey{glsunit}{a.u.}{\glsunit}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{physchmunits}{%
    % Longtable Umgebung
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
        {\begin{longtable}{cccc}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
    % Table Header
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        \toprule%
        \bfseries Symbol & \bfseries Name & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit %
        \midrule%
        \\\endhead}%
    % No heading between groups:
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    % Haupteinträge:
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glossentrysymbol{##1}% Symbol
        & \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}% Name
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description / Beschreibung
        & \glsunit{##1}% Unit
        & ##2% page list
        \tabularnewline % end of row
        }%
    % Untereinträge
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        \glossentrysymbol{##2}% Symbol
        & \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}% Name
        & \glossentrydesc{##2}% Description
        & \glsunit{##2}% Unit
        & ##3% Page list
        \tabularnewline % end of row
        }%
    % Nothing between groups
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}
    
% ========== SYMBOLS ==========
\newglossaryentry{sy:SA}{%
    name={specific activity},%
    description={specific activity},%
    symbol={SA},%
    glsunit={sa},%
    type={symbols}%
    }%
    
\newglossaryentry{SA}{%
    name={specific activity},%
    description={specific activity},%
    symbol={SA},%
    glsunit={sa},%
    type={symbols}%
    }%
% ========== ACRONYMS ==========
\newacronym{ecsa}{ECSA}{electrochemically active surface area}%


% ==============================
\begin{document}
text

%\ac{ecsa}\\
%\ac{ecsa}\\
\acf{ecsa}\\%
text
\ac{ecsa}\\%
text
\gls{SA}\\%
text
\gls{sy:SA}%

\printglossaries
%\printsymbols
\printsymbols[style=physchemunits,nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

Which, if I try to run it, results in an error code:

"Error line 1
! File ended while scanning use of \newglossarystyle.

\par
<*> ./testMain2.tex
?
! Emergency stop.

\par
<*> ./testMain2.tex"

Right now I have no idea how to resolve the error or even where to look for it, so if there is anybody out there that might have a solution or just another idea what to test or check, I would be very apreciative of your input.

Thank You!

*Edit* - I checked again and indeed found two missing closing braces after both occurences of `\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}`

Now I have another error code showing up:
"! Misplaced \noalign.
\midrule ->\noalign
{\ifnum 0=`}\fi @aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global @...
l.25 \begin{theglossary}\glossaryheader"
Which is at least something new I can investigate ;-)

*Edit 2* - It turns out, the error was a result of a missing `\\` before the `\midrule` term.
The next error was:
"! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr."
which was caused because the `\glossentry` and `\subglossentry` used more columns than I had defined in the

```
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
        {\begin{longtable}{@{}clp{7cm}cc@{}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
```

After solving this issue, the MWE now is compiling without errors.

```
%%% === ARARA === %%%
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: makeglossaries
%%% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }


\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

% ==============================
% ========== ACRONYMS AND GLOSSARY ==========

\usepackage[xindy, acronym, symbols, shortcuts, toc]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\glsaddstoragekey{glsunit}{a.u.}{\glsunit}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{physchemunits}{%
    % Longtable Umgebung
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
        {\begin{longtable}{@{}clp{7cm}cc@{}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
    % Table Header
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        \toprule%
        \bfseries Symbol & \bfseries Name & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit %
        \\\midrule%
        \\\endhead}%
    % No heading between groups:
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    % Haupteinträge:
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glossentrysymbol{##1}% Symbol
        & \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}% Name
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description / Beschreibung
        & \glsunit{##1}% Unit
        & ##2% page list
        \tabularnewline % end of row
        }%
    % Untereinträge
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
        \glossentrysymbol{##2}% Symbol
        & \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}% Name
        & \glossentrydesc{##2}% Description
        & \glsunit{##2}% Unit
        & ##3% Page list
        \tabularnewline % end of row
        }%
    % Nothing between groups
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}
    
% ========== SYMBOLS ==========
\newglossaryentry{sy:SA}{%
    name={specific activity},%
    description={specific activity},%
    symbol={SA},%
    glsunit={sa},%
    type={symbols}%
    }%
    
\newglossaryentry{SA}{%
    name={specific activity},%
    description={specific activity},%
    symbol={SA},%
    glsunit={sa},%
    type={symbols}%
    }%
% ========== ACRONYMS ==========
\newacronym{ecsa}{ECSA}{electrochemically active surface area}%


% ==============================
\begin{document}
iksldklskdlk

%\ac{ecsa}\\
%\ac{ecsa}\\
\acf{ecsa}\\%
sdsdaaasd
\ac{ecsa}\\%
asdasdasd
\gls{SA}\\%
asdasda
\gls{sy:SA}%

\printglossaries
%\printsymbols
\printsymbols[style=physchemunits,nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

Comment: well at first you are missing various closing braces. Use some editor which highlights braces and check all of them.

Comment: Thank You for the hint.
I have been using Notepad++ and TexMaker to do exactly this. However, both seem to have issues recognizing connected braces when the sequence `{%`  is involved, which seems to be common practice at least in the glossaries handbook.
Is it possible you ran into the same phenomenon when testing the code?
Using both editors and also checking "manually" I failed to find missing closing brackets.
Also, when rewriting the \newglossarystyle, I used the "auto-complete brackets" option built in in the editor to try to avoid this issue.

Comment: _Update_ - I checked again and indeed found two missing closing braces after both occurences of `\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}`